# Improving ruby code performance with threading not working

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I am trying to optimize this piece of ruby code with Thread, which involves a fair bit of IO and network activity. Unfortunately that is not going down too well.

```
# each host is somewhere in the local network
hosts.each { |host|
  # reach out to every host with something for it to do
  # wait for host to complete the work and get back
}
```

My original plan was to wrap the internal of the loop into a new Thread for each iteration. Something like:

```
# each host is somewhere in the local network
hosts.each { |host|
  Thread.new { 
  # reach out to every host with something for it to do
  # wait for host to complete the work and get back
  }
}

# join all threads here before main ends
```

I was hoping that since this I/O bound even without ruby 1.9 I should be able to gain something but nope, nothing. Any ideas how this might be improved?

Comment: Have you measured how long it takes to do a single task, and how long it takes to do n tasks, where n is less than the number of hosts?

Comment: @Andrew: single - 8s, N - 11s

Comment: How many hosts are there? How many threads you are creating? Have you tried creating less threads or reusing them? You would surely need a thread-pool or blocking queue implementation to make sure you're not using too many resources at the same time. Also, threading is not the best option for improving your code performance in ruby.

Comment: If you're taking 8 seconds for a single task, and 11 seconds to do multiple tasks, you're doing fine.

Comment: It's also worth checking if you're binding to TCP at the C level if you're looking for more performance.

Comment: What Ruby are you using? Matz ruby that doesn't have real threads or JRuby that does?

Comment: Depending on the build of Ruby, you might be able to create a lot of threads, but because of the Global Interpreter Lock, only one will be able to run at any given time, basically rendering your threading useless in most cases.

Comment: @Romain: The GIL doesn't affect IO.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm hence "In most cases". If the code is heavily IO-bound, then yes, it will help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how many hosts you have, but if it's a lot you may want to try a producer/consumer model with a fixed number of threads:

```
require 'thread'

THREADS_COUNT = (ARGV[0] || 4).to_i

$q = Queue.new
hosts.each { |h| $q << h }

threads = (1..THREADS_COUNT).map {
  Thread.new {
    begin
      loop {
        host = $q.shift(true)

       # do something with host
      }
    rescue ThreadError
      # queue is empty, pass
    end
  }
}

threads.each(&:join)
```

If this all too complicated, you may try using [xargs -P](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html#xargs-options). ;)

Answer (score 1):

@Fanatic23, before you draw any conclusions, instrument your code with `puts` and see whether the network requests are actually overlapping. In each call to `puts`, print a status string indicating the line which is executing, along with `Time.now` and `Time.now.nsec`.

Answer (score -1):

You say "since this [is] I/O bound even without ruby 1.9 I should be able to gain something".

Vain hope. :-)

When a thread in Ruby 1.8 blocks on IO, the entire process has blocked on IO. This is because it's using green theads.

Upgrade to Ruby 1.9, and you'll have access to your platform's native threads implementation.  For more, see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads

Enjoy!

Comment: According to http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2011/ruby-concurrency-and-you/ , MRI 1.8.7 knows to switch threads when there's IO happening, so for an IO bound program, using multiple threads can help even in 1.8.7 .

Comment: Ruby 1.8 uses green threads. Green threads are not operating system threads; they're emulated in a single operating system thread. When the operating system thread blocks on IO, there is no opportunity for Ruby to schedule another green thread.

Comment: Or rather let me ask, when the operating system thread blocks on IO, when does Ruby get an opportunity to schedule another green thread?

Comment: Are you saying the blog post is wrong, or that I've misread it?

Comment: I think you're interpreting the blog post out of context. It's talking about Ruby scheduling a sleep on wait channel.  That's entirely interruptible and works in green threads. However, when that thread wakes up and reads on the channel, the entire process is in kernel context for the duration of that read. During that time, green thread scheduling simply cannot occur, because the software that does the scheduling isn't running.

Comment: Hmmm. Andrew, I think I get where you're coming from. The OP showed example code that is more likely than not going to spend most of its time waiting for data to become available, not reading the data. I don't consider that an I/O bound application, and I think *that's* the source of our disagreement. What do you think?

Comment: Does the blog post say that it's in kernel context while reading, or is that your understanding based on other sources?

Comment: Other sources (namely, the FreeBSD and Linux kernels). See "I/O and scheduling" at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29 for both validation of the Engine Yard article and confirmation of what I'm saying. Yes, Ruby itself can work around interrupted scheduling, and no you can't use threads to increase IO throughput in a truly IO bound Ruby application.

Comment: How do you know that Ruby 1.8 doesn't use non-blocking I/O under the hood? Have you read the source?

Comment: You're right. I've done some digging, and Ruby uses non-blocking reads. Although the Ruby 1.8 VM maps to a single kernel schedulable entity, an IO bound process invariably spends a lot of time waiting, and so non-blocking reads (even green threads) should yeild a throughput gain.

Comment: So... is it acceptable behaviour for me to just delete my whole answer? I imagine that means everyone's comments will go away as well.